# iOS Swift FIrebase: moving data to another firebase ref

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a simple shopping list app backed/synced by a firebase and items added by multiple users. I've created data structs for "GroceryItem" and "Users".

One feature of my app is that you can click the cell and it will put a checkmark next to the item as well as change a bool of "completed" to true.

I'm trying to make a button where it will it will moved all check marked items to a separate list called "history".

Below is one of my many failed attempts at this. I also included the error that XCode is giving me:

*'Element' (aka 'AnyObject') is not convertible to 'FDataSnapshot'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?*

```
@IBAction func itemsBoughtACTION(sender: AnyObject) {
        ref.queryOrderedByChild("completed").observeEventType(.Value,
            withBlock: { snapshot in

        for item in snapshot.children {
            var lastItem = GroceryItem(item)

            }
        })
    }
```

EDIT: I just want to data some data already stored in firebase, move it to another firebase location and delete the original.

Comment: Are you calling this function from code and passing it a snapshot?

Comment: I'm new to firebase, it was my understanding a snapshot was the only way to do this. Was I misinformed?

Comment: The error you describe indicates you may be calling the itemsBoughtACTION from code and passing it a FDataSnapshot. If so, you don't want to do that. The itemsBroughtAction looks like it's hooked up to a NSButton in your UI so the press of that button will pass the NSButton that was pressed to that method. Once you are in that method, you can then create a query, get your snapshots and process the data. Let us know what the situation is.. I could be off base in my guess here.

Comment: This is correct. I have a current firebase data model w/ data. When the button that is connected to itemsBoughtACTION is pressed I want all items in the list with the "completed" attribute with a value of true to be saved in a separate firebase list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process is: query for the data you want, write it out to another node, and then delete it from the original node.

Your code above won't work as it's expecting to be passed a control from the UI instead of a FDataSnapshot. If you have already done the query and have the dataset, you should create a function that would be passed a FDataSnapshot as a parameter and process it accordingly.

To simplify the answer, assume that you need to get the snapshot and process it when the button is clicked.

There's a lot of different ways to approach this, here's one conceptual option ( untested so don't copy paste)

```
        //method is called when a button in the UI is clicked/tapped.
        @IBAction func itemsBoughtACTION(sender: AnyObject) {

           let rootRef = Firebase(url:"https://your-Firebase.firebaseio.com")

           let groceryRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("groceryLists")

           //get each child node of groceryRef where completed == true
           groceryRef.queryOrderedByChild("completed").queryEqualToValue(true)
       .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

              //set up a history node and write the snapshot.value to it
              // using the key as the node name and the value as the value.
              let historyNode = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("history")
              let thisHistoryNode = historyNode.childByAppendingPath(snapshot.key)
              thisHistoryNode.setValue(snapshot.value) //write to the new node

              //get a reference to the data we just read and remove it
              let nodeToRemove = groceryRef.childByAppendingPath(snapshot.key)
              nodeToRemove.removeValue();

           })

        }
```

Comment: on the 2nd to last line of the functions:let nodeToRemove = groceryRef.childByAppendingValue(snapshot.key) xcode says Value of type 'Firebase' has no member 'childByAppendingValue'

Comment: also, thank you very much for the help. It works minus removing the old reference but this is a great start....thank you

Comment: As I said, don't copy paste! It was supposed to read .childByAppendingPath. Answer was updated. You can also set a nodes value to nil which will remove it as well. If my answer helped, please accept it.

Comment: Works perfect, answer accepted thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2 version of Jay's answer **

```
let rootRef = Firebase(url:"https://your-Firebase.firebaseio.com")
let groceryRef = ref.child("groceryLists").childByAutoId()

groceryRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "completed").queryEnding(atValue: true)
        .observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let historyNode = rootRef.child(snapshot.key)
            thisHistoryNode.setValue(snapshot.value)

            //get a reference to the data we just read and remove it
            let nodeToRemove = nodeToRemove.child(snapshot.key)
            nodeToRemove.removeValue();
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for putting that together.