# Trying Tree Walking algorithm using for loop for Firebase on Swift to save a tree of data with different node lengths per key

Tags: swift, algorithm, loops, tree, firebase

Essentially I've made an app that utilizes Firebase in Swift for iOS that allows it's users to note the pieces and parts of a greater whole using a Tree Style database.  Currently I am trying to copy a tree of information from one reference on firebase to another reference.  There is a question similar thread which can be found here: [iOS Swift FIrebase: moving data to another firebase ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143450/ios-swift-firebase-moving-data-to-another-firebase-ref).  I will even note the other threads asker is using a similar tutorial as a starting point however, I took a different approach.  The answer referenced is helpful however only deals with copying one node with one firebase reference, where as my project has many more nodes and further depth, which means using an array of of the original snapshot values to append the key.name to the reference than returning a snapshot of that new reference, then the next, and continue to dive many levels deep, then reconstruct the whole tree at a new reference.

[very rudimentary code...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH448.png)

I apologize as this is the first question I am asking and I am still terribly new to programming.  Any help or pointers to better understand what I'm trying to accomplish would be much appreciated.

A quick basic look at how the database is set up under each users ID is here.  Imagine the data branching >5-10 nodes deep
[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8iHa.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Put it in your post. That makes it much easier to answer questions.

Comment: Firebase nodes are very much like a Dictionary. You can read a node into a snapshot, then dict = snapshot.value. Then write the dict out to another node and bang, instant copy. However... why are you doing this? Referencing data is sometimes a better solution than copying it. Can you please post a snippet of your structure as text (no images or links!) as well as a code snippet. Most importantly a use case - explain why this needs to be done.

Comment: Not only for code, but also for your JSON data structure: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.